# Using custom SKNodes in spritekit scene editor

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skscene

I want to create a level using my custom subclasses of SKNode. I tried adding an SKNode to the scene editor and using the "Custom Class" tab give the class that I want it to be but that did absolutely nothing. The node would still be empty and nothing would show when I run the simulator. Also, to make sure that the class actually works, I added an instance of it to the scene programmatically to see if it shows and it does.

How do I add my custom nodes to the scene through the scene editor?

Here's my custom class code:

```
class Player: SKSpriteNode {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        print("Test")
        self.addChild(SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Player.png"))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two things you need to do:

1) When setting the Custom Class you have to prefix the class name with your app's name; `My_App_Name.MyClass` for example, where `_` represents a space.

2) Your `SKNode` subclass needs to implement `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`.

---

For example, in my project called 'MyGame':

[image]

```
class MyNode: SKSpriteNode {
    // Set this after the node has been initaliser by init(coder:)
    var someStat: Int = 0

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        // To check it worked:
        print("Yup, all working")
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I did this and in my coder init I added an SKSpriteNode with the graphic to the node, but still it will not show up in my scene without code.

Comment: Humm...that's strange; it's definitely working for me. Have you tried cleaning and then running it again? What kind of node are you trying to set the custom class of?

Comment: do you mind posting the code from your custom subclass?

Comment: Ok, when I print out something from init(coder:), it does get printed but why isn't the sprite node being added? I'm doing something like this: `self.addChild(SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Player.png"))`

Comment: Which sprite node isn't being added? Can you see the sprite node you added in the editor? Do you definitely have an image named `"Player.png"`? Try just `"Player"`...

Comment: Yes, I am sure I have this image, it appeared when I created the node in code and added it to the scene. And no, it does not appear in the editor.

Comment: I've added another edit to my question with some working code of adding an `SKSpriteNode`. But without having your code to look at it's very difficult to diagnose the problem.

Comment: And does the orange box indeed appear in your scene?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82648/discussion-between-abakersmith-and-youssef-sami).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Xcode 8. 
It sounds stupid, but to apply a custom class I had to **save** the .sks file before running.

.sks files are not saved automatically, unlike text files or storyboards.