# How can a sprite created in the Sprite Kit scene editor receive touch event

Tags: sprite-kit

If a "sprite" is created with "SKSpriteNode()", I guess we can override "touchesBegan" function to receive its touch events. However, how can we do that when the Sprite Kit scene editor is used?
Following is the class used as the "custom class":

```
class Card : SKSpriteNode
{
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        // To check it worked:
        print("Yup, all working")
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        print("Card : touch event")
    }
}
```

Comment: Xcode 7 supports custom classes.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Any idea is the "custom class" ready? Downloaded Xcode7 but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31230666/using-custom-sknodes-in-spritekit-scene-editor/31255481#31255481

Comment: Thanks. With the link your posted, My Class - Card's "init" is called. However still no luck with the "touchesBegan" :((

Comment: @Waterstar did you set userInteractionEnabled property to true?

Comment: Thanks guys. It works after the flag is enabled.